# UIPageViewController indicators don't change color

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I've read many other threads here about this problem, it appears that the best solution now is to set it as follows:

```
 let pageControl = UIPageControl.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height*14/15, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height))
    pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 147/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1)
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    view.addSubview(pageControl)
```

But for some reason, this does not work for me. Page control background changes its color, but the indicators remain white.

My entire viewDidLoad() method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnboardingPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    let startingViewController:OnboardingPageContentViewController  = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)!

    let viewControllers:Array<OnboardingPageContentViewController> = [startingViewController]

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let pageControl = UIPageControl.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height*14/15, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height))
    pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 147/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1)
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    view.addSubview(pageControl)
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
    self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> it appears that the best solution now is to set it as follows:

No, it isn't. You are adding a *new* UIPageControl, but the UIPageViewController *already* has a UIPageControl. What you want is to set the attributes of *that* UIPageControl.

The way to do that is to use the `appearance` proxy. Example:

```
    let proxy = UIPageControl.appearance()
    proxy.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6)
    proxy.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    proxy.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you show how to apply it to existing pageViewController, like in my code inside ViewDidLoad() method? I don't know how to access the existing UIPageControl

Comment: Holy crap, I added this code inside ViewDidLoad() and worked like magic. Thanks!

Comment: `applicationDidFinishLaunching` would be a better location.

Comment: I have two pageViewControllers, but I want to customize only one of them, I suppose moving it to applicationDidFinishLaunching could affect both of them

Comment: if you want to customize specifics pageViewControllers, you can use `UIPageControl.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:)`